# phoenix through upload bulk csv file command not understand?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I want to upload bulk csv file using phonix but I can not understood below command. Can you explain me in details ?

```
  HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase mapredcp):/path/to/hbase/conf hadoop jar phoenix-<version>-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table EXAMPLE --input /data/example.csv
```

I take this command from following website.
https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer. But here it is. You are first setting the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and then call the executable  "hadoop" with jar options to look for phoenix client jar and the class to run with parameters.
The following can help you to understand hadoop command usage (try typing hadoop on your ssh shell)

```
 Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] [COMMAND | CLASSNAME]
  CLASSNAME            run the class named CLASSNAME
 or
  where COMMAND is one of:
  fs                   run a generic filesystem user client
  version              print the version
  jar <jar>            run a jar file
                       note: please use "yarn jar" to launch
                             YARN applications, not this command.
  checknative [-a|-h]  check native hadoop and compression libraries availability
  distcp <srcurl> <desturl> copy file or directories recursively
  envvars              display computed Hadoop environment variables
  archive -archiveName NAME -p <parent path> <src>* <dest> create a hadoop archive
  classpath            prints the class path needed to get the
  credential           interact with credential providers
                       Hadoop jar and the required libraries
  daemonlog            get/set the log level for each daemon
  trace                view and modify Hadoop tracing settings

Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters.
```